# Neo4j 1.9 Cypher Issue with "Has" Clause

Tags: nosql, neo4j, cypher

I'm migrating to Neo4j 1.9 and updating the cypher queries according to the [deprecations](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/1.9/deprecations.html) migration guide, specifically:

> The ! property operator in Cypher Expressions like node.property! =
>   "value" have been deprecated, please use has(node.property) AND
>   node.property = "value" instead.

The problem is that when using the *HAS* clause in combination with *NOT* I can't get the expected result. For example:

**When the status property exists and is set to something other than "DONE":**

```
AND not(n.status! = "DONE")
```

evaluates true (as expected)

```
AND not(has(n.status) AND n.status = "DONE")
```

evaluates false???

**When the status property doesn't exist**

```
AND not(n.status! = "DONE")
```

evaluates false

```
AND not(has(n.status) AND n.status = "DONE")
```

throws exception because the node doesn't exist, surely *HAS* should have prevented this? It's as though wrapping the check in *NOT* prevents the *HAS* check from being executed.

This can be reproduced via the [live query examples on the neo4j docs website](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-where.html#where-property-exists) using the following queries:

```
MATCH n 
WHERE NOT (n.name! = 'Peter') 
RETURN n
```

This returns all (3) nodes who either have no name or whose name is not "Peter". This is the result I want to reproduce but without using the now deprecated "!" operator.

```
MATCH n 
WHERE NOT (HAS (n.name) AND n.name = 'Peter') 
RETURN n
```

Throws a node not found exception because one node doesn't have a name property. :/

```
MATCH n 
WHERE (HAS (n.name) AND n.name = 'Peter') 
RETURN n
```

Correctly returns the node whose name is "Peter".

I've tried rewriting the query in a few alternative ways but can't seem to reliably get the result I want that matches the deprecated ! operator. Maybe it's just getting late and I'm missing something obvious? :)

Any Help is appreciated!

Thanks,
Mark.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the second query raising an exception is a bug.

What you can do is use [de Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to transform the predicate:

```
MATCH n 
WHERE NOT (HAS (n.name)) OR (n.name <> 'Peter') 
RETURN n
```

Comment: Thomas's suggestion is correct. He's also right about the bug, although future Neo4j versions will likely treat a missing name property as null, rather than throwing an exception.

Comment: Thanks, is it worth raising this as a bug?

Comment: So to clarify it looks like anytime you negate the HAS clause and use it in a conjunction it results in this bug.